# How do I get more muffins?

Tags: pony-clicker

There are multiple upgrades that increase Smiles-per-second (SPS) per each muffin you have, which I have a few now, but I have never clicked on or purchased any muffins.

Where did I get the ones I have and how can I get more?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling in the source code it looks like Muffins are gained through achievements and are a sort of Achievement Points.  Some achievements such as the "Hi There!" and "Participation Award" achievements don't grant any muffins, while the "Mayor Mare" achievement grants 5 muffins.  To make a full list of the muffins granted by each achievement might be a bit long for this format though so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: Comments in the source code also indicate some sort of muffin prestige system that is not fully built yet

Comment: I just tested this by buying a "building" until I got an achievement and it indeed increased my muffin count.